# Laravel Sail Docker Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, phpmyadmin, laravel-sail

I have a problem with my Laravel 8 Sail. The container works fine, but when i tried to in to phpmyadmin i can't, because page only show the logo of phpmyadmin, but don't show o form for into application.

I take a picture of problem.

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF4ZI.png)

Share my docker-compose.yaml file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: "3"
services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
      context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
    image: sail-7.4/app
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}"
    environment:
      WWWUSER: "${WWWUSER}"
      LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
      XDEBUG_MODE: "${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}"
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}"
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - sail
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
    ports:
      - "${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - "sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh"
    networks:
      - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    networks:
      - sail
    depends_on:
      - mysql
networks:
  sail:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  sail-mysql:
    driver: local
```

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Are there any hints logged to the webserver error log (which you can get by examining the Docker log output for the phpMyAdmin container)?

Comment: There isn't, it doesn't show the logs...I'll build the container again and see if it generates the logs...

Comment: Something must be wrong with your Docker setup then; you should at least see information in the log that Apache is starting and so on, even if you don't see an error message. I'd look in to that first. How are you examining the logs?